# Experimental German spelling of capitals?

Tags: spelling, history, capitalization

I casually run into a strange spelling of German, I suspect it was just an experimental one. If you open a volume of the **Zeitschrift für deutsches Altertum und deutsche Literatur** of the 20s (for example [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/i20657069)) you'll notice that not only it lacks capitalization of nouns, but even at the beginning of the sentences the capital letters were abolished. They were only used for proper names. An example is attached below. What I wish to ask is some reference to the history of this spelling: who was the proponent? how did it end?
[image]

Comment: Thanks for asking, I too was wondering because it's also like that in the [FEW](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/) (Französisches Etymologisches Wörterbuch). The answer talks about _philologists_, which is spot on considering what the FEW is. I'm ashamed to say that it's only when I posted a Q. here that I learned about the rule for capitalizing nouns, as well as for the direction of quotes » x «. In my defense where I come from we know very little about the German language and Germany generally. A shame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a spelling was proposed by the Grimm brothers in the early 19th century. It gained some popularity among philologists, but unfortunately, it did not catch on.

Comment: Could you add some more details?

Comment: "Unfortunately" - not sure. I find un-capitalized German text much harder to read than properly upper-cased sentences.

Comment: @tofro: That is what many Danes said as well – before they abolished noun captalization (the Germans were not the only ones). Afterwards, nobody missed it.

Comment: @mach the most surprising here is the uncapitalized beginning of the sentence. I think this is the only known case in the modern European languages and orthographies.

Comment: German has a greater variability in word order, which is, why capitalizing substantives is more helpful than in many other languages.

Comment: @userunknown same can be said about many other European languages.

Comment: @ArtemijKeidan. The Grimm dictionary is on line: http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB

Comment: @ArtemijKeidan there is not that much of a story behind it. The capitalization thing was a fashion you find in alot of european languages or found in alot of european languages during a short time period (with just traces like capitalization at the beginning of sentences left today). It's just that e.g. the Grimms where not intressted in fashions in language, but having a "smooth" developments and therefore avoided it and hoped all the new readers and writers (due to rising literacy by the common people at the time) would adapt that. Something like that.